# Which form is best for React and ReactNative, Formik vs React Hook Form vs React Reactive Form?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-hook-form

I am working on an application having nested forms. I am confused about which of them is best. I worked on react-reactive-form and it fulfils all the requirements of my app but has some issues with nested structure, especially with FormArray(to add new, prefill form array and delete the array element from a particular index). Basically, I need to do some extra code to achieve these.

After this, I saw lots of people using "Formik", especially when working with React. I'm new to Formik, I didn't know whether it's better in performance or not. Also, I didn't see any article that explains their technical performance part.
There is just a downloads comparison I found:: https://npmtrends.com/formik-vs-react-reactive-form

Formik: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik
React Reactive Form: https://github.com/bietkul/react-reactive-form
or React Hook Form:: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form

**My requirements:**

- need to use multiple and nested form structures inside my application.
- require form validations of change, on blur or submit
- handle data in the array where I can add new items dynamically, and also delete, add and update anything.
- Most important:: Can pass controls to another component as reactive form does. This means if we want to create a form in the parent and then subdivide the form sections into components where we can pass that section form field controls to the child component and still after on change can get complete form values at one place that is at parent component.

Which of them is best in terms of performance, and can achieve all the parts easily I have mentioned.

Comment: I can't speak for `Reactive Form`, but I've used `Formik` in multiple projects and it's pretty great.

Comment: Even I have used Formik in RN, but would like to know the pros and cons of other libraries

Comment: @Nathan, ok thanks. I just want to know about their technical performance, because I worked with React reactive Form and never tried Formik. I want to know whether its useful to switch the form or not.

Comment: @Azzy, same case here, I have just used React Reactive Form and now I want to know about Formik.

Answer (score -2):

use `react-bootstrap` for Form, Input, Button, etc